# How can I override TTL of an Internet Address?

Tags: linux, bind, dnsmasq

I'm running a caching DNS server currently to improve latency in a network.

The question is: can I override the TTL I get from a server using BIND9 or other software on Linux?

short "dig www.google.com" here:

; <<>> DiG 9.6.1-P2 <<>> www.google.com

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.  604441 IN CNAME www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com. 300 IN A 74.125.45.147

Can I change that '300' into 15 minutes?

Thanks you so much for your time!!.

Comment: As mentioned several times, please don't do this. Just take a quick look around on serverfault to find out how many questions there are from sysadmins who have to deal with DNS servers that don't obey the TTL. Try: http://serverfault.com/questions/54758/how-long-does-it-take-for-dns-to-update-new-records-strange-dns-behaviour or http://serverfault.com/questions/103281/why-did-this-website-dns-change-fail-in-some-parts-of-the-us or http://serverfault.com/questions/96453/dns-not-resolving-for-some-people-locations

Comment: Do not worry it was a proof of concept, that CAN be done. Also this will not propagate more than 2 people in this network.
And this was part as an Academic effort to show a internet connection with the lowest latency possible.
I understand your concerns. This was the first time I use this web page, and I'm amazed by the good replies.

Comment: Also see @derobert's answer. He provides a couple different options and a links to explanations: How to configure bind9 caching period:
[http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162267/how-to-configure-bind9-caching-period/162314#162314](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162267/how-to-configure-bind9-caching-period/162314#162314)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the DIRTIEST most ugliest thing that can be done is...

1-Downloading the source
2-find the file called cache.c
3-find the function is_expired

4- Change it in this way

```
static int is_expired(time_t now, struct crec *crecp)
{
  if (crecp->flags & F_IMMORTAL)
    return 0;

  if (difftime(now, crecp->ttd) < 0)
    return 0;

  return 0; // IT WAS IN ONE
}
```

When the function ask did expire? we always saw no

In this way it will never expire and you will conquer the world.

OUTPUT:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.6.1-P2 <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28477
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     603937  IN  CNAME   www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com.   4294966733 IN   A   209.85.195.99
www.l.google.com.   4294966733 IN   A   209.85.195.104
www.l.google.com.   4294966733 IN   A   209.85.195.147

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 17 18:34:47 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 110
```

Comment: +1 for continuous urge to take over the world (and learn in the process).

Comment: It doesn't look like this even does what the question asks for; it seems to make the record never expire rather than make it have a TTL of 15m.

Answer (score 7):

**CAN** this be done? Sure - there are broken DNS servers (e.g. the ones AOL runs) that do this, and every admin I know hates it.

**SHOULD** this be done? Almost certainly no.

Generally speaking the TTL was set to a particular value for a reason (in google's case, probably fault tolerance: You'll only be unable to reach google for 5 minutes if that server blows up), and you shouldn't muck about with it.

You're already getting a performance boost by keeping the google.com record in your cache for the 5 minutes it's intended to live for since your individual workstations won't be running out to the internet for resolution -- don't over-optimize and break the expected behavior :)

Comment: should I change the question and say: how can I run a evil, not standard compliant server, so evil it cache for 15 minutes? So I can learn "what shouldn't be done". Thanks you everyone for the quick responses. –

Comment: You could TAKE OVER THE WORLD this way. Muaaahahahaha. Yes. Evil.

Comment: yes, and learning in the process, amazing!
I'm sure it can be done, but I can't seem to find an answer...
Maybe with some crazy BIND9 configuration zone...

Comment: Well, my general intent was to convince you *not* to do it.  If you insist the only way I know of would be to actually to patch BIND to add a `min-cache-ttl` configuration directive (analogous in function to the existing `max-cache-ttl`).  AFAIK no caching DNS server in the wild allows you to do this, though I haven't looked at Microsoft's...

Comment: I thought that as well. I'm downloading dnsmasq source as we speak.
I believe will be easier to patch dnsmasq because the source code to analyze is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really interested in history rather than accuracy, the *quickest* dirtiest hack you can do is probably make your name server an authoritative master for the domain and recreate the zonefile as frequently as needed through a script.  Definitely only recommended for taking over the world though, not for real life.

In general if you really want a record of very short TTL to persist within an application, it seems the only sensible way is to cache it within the application.

Answer (score 2):

**Min TTL**

**Yes**, you can do this in ISC Bind with a simple change to their source code.  They will not provide a mechanism for you to do this for ideological reasons.

**Yes**, you can also set or override the **min-ttl** of recursive DNS requests in **[Unbound DNS](https://www.unbound.net)** without having to recompile anything.  That said, you *should* compile the latest version, as the 1.4 branch in the EPEL repo has a few bugs that will not be fixed and so that you can set all of the glibc hardening flags.

```
cache-min-ttl: 60
```

While it is correct that folks should use caution when applying this on recursors used by many applications and/or people, there are several use cases where it may be appropriate.  This assumes the person overriding min-ttl understands what applications are utilizing their DNS infrastructure and what impact overriding this can have.  To say that it should never be done would be an incorrect generalization.

**My Personal Experience**

I have used the `cache-min-ttl:` setting in Unbound DNS to mitigate some privacy attacks of tracking websites.  I have also used it to correct invalid DNS set by folks that are setting a TTL of `0` which technically violates a few RFC's.  Given that I control my own recursors and they are only used by me, the risk is very low.

Answer (score -1):

See similar question here [dnsmasq: how to increase TTL?](https://serverfault.com/questions/86968/dnsmasq-how-to-increase-ttl) and another one here [Is there an alternative to "dnsmasq"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/86970/is-there-an-alternative-to-dnsmasq)

Comment: in that question it doesn't fix my problem. I need to cache for longer periods of time (more than 300 seconds) one particular web site.

Comment: The dnsmasq article point to this:
"Normally responses which come form /etc/hosts and the DHCP lease
file have Time-To-Live set as zero, which conventionally means
do not cache further. If you are happy to trade lower load on the
server for potentially stale date, you can set a time-to-live (in
seconds) here."
And is not what I'n looking to accomplish.
I want to use an address resolved by the dns for a longer period than the one I been given

Comment: @omniwired - The reason you can reduce the TTL is because TTL = "You *may* cache this record for *at most* S seconds".  Good, Correct DNS servers shouldn't ever let you cache records longer than their TTL...