# Is is possible to set up different DNS records based on the realtime qps using bind?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm trying to set up a self hosted DNS server for my website using bind and I want to set it to redirect to a custom error site (set all records to CNAME of `error.my.domain` maybe) if the qps reaches a threshold, and change the respective records back after a set period (say, 10 mins or so).

Is it possible to do so using only bind configs? If not, are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: **Note** that you don't control how well others honour the TTL of your DNS records and using such an approach is not always guaranteed to work in a timely fashion.

Comment: ISC Bind doesn't have a built in health check function to monitor external services, but you can for example have your monitoring and alerting trigger script to update your DNS records with the `nsupdate` command. 

See for example an older answer of mine [here](https://serverfault.com/a/667834/37681) and the manual https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9.18.21/reference.html#dynamic-update-policies.